# Private key problem and stolen money by trader

Tags: go-ethereum, private-key, trustwallet

I gave money to a trader . for example 300€ and now he gave me the address 0x4c8FeB3e02C67408d36c663Ad868d215B1B3239E
and he told me that if i will give him 500€ he will give the private key for my profits . help me

Comment: There's nothing you could do, either walk away with the 300 loss or contact your local authorities to report the trader.

Answer (score 0):

DON'T SEND HIM ANYTHING!!!!! That is a scam. He is just trying to get even more money from you!

I assume he asked you to "invest" some money into him. And promised he would give you a return on that investment.

Now he claims he managed to turn your 300Euro to 10K, but is asking 500 Euros to give it back to you.

That is a scam; try to gather/save all the data you have on him (Your conversations etc.). Plus the accounts you paid to. It might help authorities locate him.